# Как подставить имя метода программно?

Tags: java

Смысл в том, что в зависимости от получаемых методом GET параметрах сервлетом необходимо выполнить тот или иной метод - `getN1FromDB`, `getN2FromDB` и т.д.
Можно ли это сделать не применяя if, программно формируя имя метода в этой части кода?

```
DAOModel model = new DAOModel();
List records = model.getN1FromDB(параметр1, параметр2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно с помощью рефлексии, но она медленная, небезопасная и в целом плохая практика использовать её, если вы не пишите средства разработки или фреймворк.

```
String methodName = "getN1FromDB";
DAOModel model = new DAOModel();
Method method = model.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, {String.class, int.class});
List records = (List) method.invoke(model, "Hello", 42);
```

Comment: Спасибо! т.е. лучше просто применить switch?

Comment: Да, лучше switch.

Answer (score 2):

Да это возможно сделать через рефлексию (Java Reflection), но это будет гораздо запарнее:

```
DAOModel model = new DAOModel();
String methodName = "getN1FromDB";
java.lang.reflect.Method myNamedMethod;
try {
  myNamedMethod = model.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
} catch (SecurityException e) { ... }
  catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { ... }
```

В данном случае параметры необходимы для того, чтобы определить метод, если существуют его переопределения разными параметрами.

Далее вызываете этот метод с помощью метода `invoke`

```
try {
 List records = (List) myNamedMethod.invoke(model, параметр1, параметр2);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { ... }
  catch (IllegalAccessException e) { ... }
  catch (InvocationTargetException e) { ... }
```

Comment: Спасибо! т.е. лучше просто применить switch?